# where is the index physically located in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, performance, index, index-tuning, datafile

Just wondering where is the index info physically located in MySQL database if I have indexed a table with `ALTER TABLE contacts ADD KEY (columnName);` ?

1. it will stay with that table and add a new spacial column to it;
2. stay separately from that table;

I think the #2 is the correct answer.

Can we index columns from more than one tables? how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the MyISAM engine, a table's indexes are stored in the `.MYI` file (in the data directory, along with the `.MYD` and `.frm` files for the table).

For InnoDB engine, the indexes are stored in the tablespace, along with the table. If `innodb_file_per_table` option is set, the indexes will be in the table's `.ibd` file along with the `.frm` file.

No, it's not possible to create an index that references more than one table. An index is specific to a table.

Comment: Is the View the same as the stored procedure regarding the location? I mean the View is also stored somewhere and will be activated when it is referred?

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL, all table information, including keys, are located in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database.

For a more detailed answer, you might want to ask on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).